# Is there a way to solve build type guess under Desktop Arm Ubuntu 20.04 in VM Fusion of M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, arm, ubuntu-20.04, ns2

Background: I should install a package called "NS2" in Ubuntu. My Ubuntu is 20.04 Version with an arm architecture. Our teacher doesn't allow us to use the 'sudo apt-get install ns2' way to install NS2 package because some latter labs won't be supported if using such a way.

First I get the file called 'ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz', then decompresses it, then run './install --build=arm-linux', and give the error:

```
============================================================
* Build OTcl-1.14
============================================================
No .configure file found in current directory
Continuing with default options...
checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2007-01-15, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

  http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.guess
and
  http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.sub

If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please
send the following data and any information you think might be
pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2007-01-15

uname -m = aarch64
uname -r = 5.15.0-69-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:06 UTC 2023

/usr/bin/uname -p = aarch64
/bin/uname -X     = 

hostinfo               = 
/bin/universe          = 
/usr/bin/arch -k       = 
/bin/arch              = aarch64
/usr/bin/oslevel       = 
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = 

UNAME_MACHINE = aarch64
UNAME_RELEASE = 5.15.0-69-generic
UNAME_SYSTEM  = Linux
UNAME_VERSION = #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:06 UTC 2023
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
otcl-1.14 configuration failed! Exiting ...
Please check http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html
for common problems and bug fixes.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVKi9.jpg)

I have renewed the file 'config.guess' and 'config.sub'. But the error is the same.

I have used the command './install --build=aarch64'. But the error is the same.

I hope the error could be solved

Answer (score 0):

I have tried ./configure --build=arm-linux on texinfo-4.13 on arm (OPi3LTS) instead of ./install --build=arm-linux and worked with configure